# At what point are Docker Variables available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker

I was doing some work with Rails, and in my database configuration, I had the following variable:

```
host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
```

Rails kept failing because it said it was trying to connect via a socket, which indicated to me that the value was empty (that's how Rails falls back).

However, every time I logged into the container, via `docker exec`, the environment variable was set correctly.

I later changed it for debugging purposes to the following:

```
host: 172.17.0.15 # <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
```

And it worked fine (this was the value reported earlier).

So my question is, at what point during a `docker run` are the docker environment variables set? Am I doing something wrong here? I guess I'd be happy to bounce nginx as the last command in my Dockerfile, but if the environment variables are still not set, it doesn't feel like that'll solve anything.

**Update**

I'm using the Dockerfile from this webpage - https://rossfairbanks.com/2015/03/06/rails-app-on-docker-using-passenger-image.html

**Update 2**
Docker Run: docker run --rm --name nginx -p 80:80 --link mysql:mysql myNginxImage

Comment: When you container first starts, the 'entrypoint' for that container will have all the environment variables set.  It would help if you could show your Dockerfile, and where the process is being started that isn't getting the environment variable. (all of the programs/scripts from the entrypoint to your process that is failing, if there is a chain).

Comment: I should probably read up more on entrypoints - added the Dockerfile source.

Comment: I should have asked, I would like to see the docker run command for this as well :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dockerfile referenced has :

```
# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

This is the 'entrypoint' if you don't override it when you do the docker run command (I'm guessing, that wasn't posted in the question either).  What is about to follow is a bunch of guesses, but, I think I have it right :-)

First, the documentation states:

> Passenger works like a mod_ruby, mod_nodejs, etc. It changes Nginx
>   into an application server and runs your app from Nginx. So to get
>   your web app up and running, you just have to add a virtual host entry
>   to Nginx which describes where you app is, and Passenger will take
>   care of the rest.

Then, later on, when describing Nginx startup:

> By default Nginx clears all environment variables (except TZ) for its
>   child processes (Passenger being one of them). That's why any
>   environment variables you set with docker run -e, Docker linking and
>   /etc/container_environment, won't reach Nginx.

This is fairly typical for init behaviors to clear env variables before launching the process.  Since nginx has had its environment variable cleared, any process that it subsequently starts will also have the env vars cleared.  Luckily, they tell you how to propagate the variables to the sub process:

> To preserve these variables, place an Nginx config file ending with
>   *.conf in the directory /etc/nginx/main.d, in which you tell Nginx to preserve these variables. For example when linking a PostgreSQL
>   container or MongoDB container:

then they show an example. You can create a file, call is mysql-env.conf, in the same directory as your Dockerfile, and it contains:

```
env MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR;
```

Then, in your Dockerfile, put the line:

```
ADD mysql-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/mysql-env.conf
```

This should leak the env variable through for you.

Comment: This is an amazingly good answer, and I missed this blurb in the docs. Thank you!